# data-types and control structures for google-docs api

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a Google app for Google Docs Spreadsheet for my office. I can find the tutorials for the Spreadsheet and UI elements but there is no one-package resource that describes the data-types and control structures that google-docs scripts uses. My background is python so I am expecting list and other relevant data types python uses in google-docs. Can somebody suggest me a place or a link where I can find all the related information about google-docs script data-types and control structure?

Comment: Are you using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Cool, I have retagged the question.

Comment: That's so funny! I was hoping to get an answer.

Comment: using the right tags makes it much easier to get answers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apps Script uses JavaScript, so for data types and control structure, you can look at any JavaScript reference. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) is one example.

For Apps Script specific classes and methods, you can see the API reference docs, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/defaultservices).